# Responsive Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a web page and I am trying to use a bootstrap carousel. On the first slide there are 3 pictures and on the other slide there is a youtube video embedded to it. The page looks problematic on smaller resolutions.

Here is a how pictures look like on laptop:
[pictures on laptop](http://s23.postimg.org/hwrwo00pn/sample1.png)

Here is how youtube video looks like on laptop:
[video on laptop](http://s18.postimg.org/53p8l3vk9/sample2.png)

Here is how pictures look like on smaller resolution:
[pictures on 320x480](http://s13.postimg.org/s9vzb5kqf/sample3.png)

Here is video on smaller resolution:
[video on 320x480](http://s11.postimg.org/b4v18qpkj/sample4.png)

Here is video on 360x640:
[video on 360x640](http://s3.postimg.org/jt6vgfngz/sample5.png)

Is there a way to make pictures on carousel display on the center when it is smaller resoultion? And of course for the youtube video as well. The video is not on the center and exceeds the screen.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">

                <div class="row item active">

                    <div class="bannerImage">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/waspmote_pro_t.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/waspmote_exp_radio_board_2-375_t.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/u13_gw_t.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="caption row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h3>Waspmote</h3>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Connect any sensor</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-rss"></i> Using any wireless technology</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> To any Cloud Platform</li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="waspmote">
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Ultra low power (0.7uA)</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> 100+ Sensors available</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Over the Air Programming (OTA)</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Encryption Libraries (AES, RSA)</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Encapsulated line available</li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="waspmote">

                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Industrial Protocolos: RS-232,RS-485,Modbus,CAN Bus, 4-20mA</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> 3G/GPRS/LoRaWAN/LoRa/Sigfox/868/900MHz,ZigBee/802.15.4/WiFi/RFID/ NFC/ Bluetooth 4.0</li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /Slide1 -->

                <div class="row item">

                    <div class="bannerImage">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/waspmoteps01.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/waspmoteps02.png" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/waspmote03.png" alt="" class="righter">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="caption row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h3>Waspmote Plug & Sense</h3>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i> Easy and fast deployment</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Minimum maintenance costs</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i> Services/network scalability</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> Any Cloud platform compatible</li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="waspmoteps">
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Integrating more than 80 sensors</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Robust waterproof IP65 enclosure</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Add/change sensor probe in seconds</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Solar powered internal and external panel</li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="waspmoteps">
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Over the air programming (OTAP)</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Graphical/intuitive programming interface</li>
                                    <li class="space"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ZigBee, 802.15.4, 868, 900, LoRaWAN, LoRa, Sigfox, WiFi, 3G/GPRS and Bluetooth Low Energy</li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /Slide2 -->
                <div class="row item">

                    <div class="bannerImage">
                        <iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/f1wXYGDvYAY?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>

                    <div class="caption row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h3>Waspmote Plug & Sense</h3>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 waspmoteps">
                                <p>The new Waspmote Plug & Sense! line allows developers to forget about electronics and focus on services and applications. Now you can deploy wireless sensor networks in a easy and scalable way ensuring minimum maintenance costs. The new platform consists of a robust waterproof enclosure with specific external sockets to connect the sensors, the solar panel, the antenna and even the USB cable in order to reprogram the node. It has been specially designed to be scalable, easy to deploy and maintain.</p>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /Slide3 -->
                <div class="row item">

                    <div class="bannerImage">
                        <iframe width="480" height="284" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GRMMS8nOdwc?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>

                    <div class="caption row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h3>Waspmote Events Sensor Board</h3>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 waspmoteps">
                                <p>More than 50 available sensors for the Waspmote platform. Values from the temperature, humidity, tilt, vibration, water, PIR, bend sensors integrated in the Events Sensor Board are sent using the 802.15.4/ZigBee radio.</p>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /Slide4 -->
            </div>

            <div class="control-box">
                <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control left">‹</a>
                <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="carousel-control right">›</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.control-box -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#myCarousel -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.span12 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

CSS

```
div {
    word-break: break-all;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

a {
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease;
    transition: all 150ms ease;
}

    a:hover {
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
        /* IE 8 */
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        /* IE7 */
        opacity: 0.6;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


/* Container */

.container-fluid {
    background: #fbf4e0;
    margin: 40px auto 10px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    max-width: 960px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


/* Page Header */

.page-header {
    background: #fbf4e0;
    margin: -30px 0px 0px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border-top: 4px solid #ccc;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

    .page-header h3 {
        line-height: 0.88rem;
        color: #000;

    }


/* Thumbnail Box */

.caption {
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

    .caption .span4,
    .caption .span8 {
        padding: 0px 20px;
    }

    .caption .span4 {
        border-right: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
    }

    .caption h3 {
        color: #000;
        line-height: 2rem;
        margin: 0 0 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    .caption p {
        font-size: 1rem;
        line-height: 1rem;
        color: #000;
    }
    .caption ul{
         color: #000;
    }

.btn.btn-mini {
    background: #a83b3b;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    color: #fbf4e0;
    font-size: 0.63rem;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

.carousel-control {
    top: 33%;
}


/* Footer */

.footer {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.69rem;
}

    .footer,
    .footer a {
        color: #fff;
    }

p.right {
    float: right;
}


::selection {
    background: #ff5e99;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #ff5e99;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

a,
a:focus,
a:active,
a:hover,
object,
embed {
    outline: none;
}

:-moz-any-link:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}

.bannerImage img {
    margin-left: 10%;

}
.bannerImage iframe{
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
}
.waspmote{
    font-size:13px;
}
.waspmoteps{
    font-size:13px;
}
.space{
    margin-bottom:34px;
}
.righter{

    margin-left:18% !important;
}
```

**edit 1: Here is what happened after media screen added**texts under pictures are not display on the screen.

[media screen](http://s11.postimg.org/l7grus4jn/sample6.png)

**edit 2: Actually this markup works for pictures in the slide but still texts under the pictures are not visible in smaller resolutions.**

```
<div class="bannerImage">
                                        <div class="row productsRow">
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <a href="#"><img src="images/waspmoteps01.png" alt=""></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <a href="#"><img src="images/waspmoteps02.png" alt=""></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <a href="#"><img src="images/waspmote03.png" alt="" class="righter"></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.productsRow {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

**Edit 3: JSFiddle added:**
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kizildagcenk/zeLh3utk/1/)

**EdiT 4: After removing the height, the videos are not centered.**
[enter link description here](http://s15.postimg.org/o3ruvmrt7/sample7.png)

**EdiT 5: Changing the iframe CSS worked for small resolutions. But for 768x1024 and 800x1280 portrait resolutions texts under pictures exceeds the screen.**

part1: [768x1024_part1](http://s4.postimg.org/vz76mhl65/sample8.png)

part2: [768x1024_part2](http://s15.postimg.org/roxu938zv/sample9.png)

**Edit 6: The PC/Laptop resolution breaks.**

[sample](http://s17.postimg.org/8ke2759zz/sample10.png)

**EdiT 7: Carousel starts on the main page automatically on IE 11 but supposed to be sliding on the active page!? Any ideas?**

Here is the Jquery:

```
// Carousel Auto-Cycle
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.carousel').carousel({
                    interval: 6000
                })
            });
```

Comment: Can you insert the current code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not perfect, but I hope it also helps you.

For your container `.bannerImage` I defined `width:100%;` than you can achieve the 
responsiveness of your website.

@media queries: To set the size of the images to 100%, if the screen resolution is lower than 1024px.

**CSS**

```
.bannerImage img {
    width: 25%;
}
.bannerImage{
    padding-left: 15%;
    padding-right: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.bannerImage iframe{
    width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  .bannerImage img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/ezp4k17u/2/)**

**EDIT 1**

Remove the `height: 140px;` on line 1430, after than your text will be shown in full height.

**EDIT 2 UPDATE**

So there was still an issue with the iframe pic, but this should fix it:

**CSS**

```
.bannerImage iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:80%;
   height:100%;
 }

.iframeImage{
   position:relative;
   padding-bottom:44.25%;
   height:0;
   left: -15%; //for centering the iframe
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bannerImage iframeImage">
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: how about the texts under pictures? It seems they don't fit on the page on your fiddle.

Comment: Removing height solved the texts under pictures but now videos are not centered when the resolution is small.

Comment: Actually it was working for smaller resolutions but I will check your new update. Please see my edit 5.

Comment: **Edit 2 update breaks the iframes** Previous CSS modification was Ok for smaller res. But as for 768x1024 and 800x1280 res. texts under pictures exceeds the screen.

Comment: Yeah the problem was `overflow: hidden;` but now the iframe should fit in the screen

Comment: should I add this iframeImage to only iframes right?

Comment: please check my edit 6. The main resolution - pc,laptop- breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `img-responsive` class for images and `embed-responsive` class for video content? these are classes for responsive media content

Check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) for images and [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed) for video content

Comment: now things getting complicated Andrew :) I am new to responsive design, would you please edit my js fiddle?

Comment: I added img-responsive and embed-responsive but there is a problem for PC/laptop resoluitons, the video and texts exceed the page [link](http://s3.postimg.org/cjmq7d5cj/sample11.png)

Comment: @Cenk you can fix this with [@media-queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), something like `@media screen and (min-width: @screen-md-min{//code for imageFrame and bannerImage}`

Comment: @MarioKurzweil I don't get it, would you please show me?

Comment: @Cenk, actually, I can not run your fiddle. It shows me only background and notheng else. you could try to follow up bootstrap examples, they are pretty good.